# My Second BackgroundWorker won't work

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have created 2 BackgroundWorkers and my second BackgroundWorker seem to not work at all, i have placed a messagebox indicator under "Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_DoWork" and it was triggered but the codess under it were not. Here is the complete code of my BackgroundWorker that is having problems. Is there something that is causing this?

i really need 2 BackgroundWorkers for my program as it is processing tons of files which makes the application hang-up.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Try
        If BackgroundWorker2.IsBusy <> True Then
            BackgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.DoWork
    Dim worker1 As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
    Try
        MessageBox.Show("the program was able to open me")
        'this message box above was able to display but the codes below were not processed 
        Dim Stream As System.IO.FileStream

        Dim Index As Integer = 0

        Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "D:\work\base tremble"
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

        If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Try
                'This line opens the file the user selected and sets the stream object
                Stream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()
                If (Stream IsNot Nothing) Then
                    'create the reader here and use the stream you got from the file open dialog
                    Dim sReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(Stream)
                    Do While sReader.Peek >= 0
                        ReDim Preserve eArray(Index)
                        eArray(Index) = sReader.ReadLine
                        RichTextBox3.Text = eArray(Index)
                        Index += 1
                        worker1.ReportProgress(Index)
                        'Delay(2)
                    Loop
                    Label1.Text = "0/" & eArray.Length & ""
                End If
            Catch Ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message)
            Finally
                If (Stream IsNot Nothing) Then
                    Stream.Close()
                End If
            End Try
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.ProgressChanged
    Try
        'Label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString()
        Me.ProgressBar2.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_Completed(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.RunWorkerCompleted
    Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot use OpenFileDialog in a worker thread.

Comment: Is there any alternative for this? my program freezes when i open a text file that has over 100,000 lines in it.

Comment: Of course, only do the slow thing in the BGW.  OpenFileDialog is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have sperated OpenFileDialog into a different button and i processed the retreiving storing of data into the array in the backgroundworker and it works now.

Thanks for the headsup about OpenFileDialog not allowed in backgroundworker it gave me a hint.